# jquery status box pop up and hide after a short while

Tags: jquery

I am try to develop a status box using jquery, so I have a button and when the button gets clicked, the status box will pop up to show message like "button is clicked" and disappear after 10 seconds, but I am not sure how to do it. 
I think the code might be like:

```
  <input type="button" id="status" value = "show status box"/>

  <script>
   $("#status").click(function(){
      //not sure what should be inside?
     }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

**html**

```
<button id="status">show status box</button>
<div id="statusmessage"></div>
```

**css**

```
#statusmessage{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    padding:0 5px;
    line-height:25px;
    background-color:#eeee99;
    margin-bottom:-25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

and **jquery**

```
$("#status").click(function() {
    $('#statusmessage').text('#status button was clicked..').animate({'margin-bottom':0},200);
    setTimeout( function(){
        $('#statusmessage').animate({'margin-bottom':-25},200);
    }, 5*1000);
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/s3fcy/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$("#status").click(function(){
      $("#new_box").show(0).delay(10000).hide(0);
});
</script>
```

Side note: you're missing one bracket `)` at the end

Comment: [make it `hide(0)` so that it will work with `delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 0):

Another form. I like the genesis' one, but for more variety

```
$("#new_box").show(200, function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#new_box").hide(200) }, 10000) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple or as complex as you want.  you could even build the elements dynamically

http://jsfiddle.net/8pqTz/

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("<div></div>").css({
    }).html("<div></div>").find("div").css({
        position:"fixed",
        width:"100%",
        height:"100%",
        left:"0px",
        top:"0px",
        background:"black",
        opacity:0.4
    }).parent().append("<div class='modal'></div>").find(".modal").css({
        width:"200px",
        height:"80px",
        position:"fixed",
        left:"50%",
        top:"50%",
        marginLeft:"-100px",
        marginTop:"-55px",
        background:"white",
        padding:"5px 10px",
        borderTop:"20px solid steelblue"
    }).text(this.id + " was pressed.").parent()
        .appendTo("body")
        .click(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        }).hide(0).fadeIn(100);
});
```

please pardon the ugly code... it's just to prove a point and yes classes would be better. :P

Comment: Hi, joseph, thanks for your answer, I want to know if I want to append a button on the modal box based on your code, how to do that, can you just show me on your code above, thank you so much.